# CSS Animations and Transitions are not working together

Tags: html, css

I have a working animation when hovering the element, it works fine but when I hover off (mouseleave) the transition is not working as expected.

I want a two-way transition:  when hovering and when moving moving off of element. ("on hover" and "off hover").

How can I achieve this?

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04phydtb/10/) and code below:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes blobby-wiggle {
  0%,
  100%,
  25%,
  50%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.02, 0.98) rotate(2deg) translate3d(2px, -2px, 0);
    transform: scale(1.02, 0.98) rotate(2deg) translate3d(2px, -2px, 0);
  }
  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.995, 1.01) rotate(1deg) translate3d(-1px, 2px, 0);
    transform: scale(0.995, 1.01) rotate(1deg) translate3d(-1px, 2px, 0);
  }
  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.01, 0.99) rotate(3deg) translate3d(1px, 1px, 0);
    transform: scale(1.01, 0.99) rotate(3deg) translate3d(1px, 1px, 0);
  }
  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.99, 1.02) rotate(4deg) translate3d(-2px, -1px, 0);
    transform: scale(0.99, 1.02) rotate(4deg) translate3d(-2px, -1px, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes project-hover {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) translateZ(0);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(20deg) rotateY(6deg) translateZ(64px);
    transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(20deg) rotateY(6deg) translateZ(64px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) translateZ(130px);
    transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) translateZ(130px);
  }
}

@keyframes project-hover {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) translateZ(0);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(20deg) rotateY(6deg) translateZ(64px);
    transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(20deg) rotateY(6deg) translateZ(64px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) translateZ(130px);
    transform: perspective(1600px) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) translateZ(130px);
  }
}

.product-heading {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-animation: blobby-wiggle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: blobby-wiggle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  &:hover {
    -webkit-animation: project-hover 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.315, 0.605, 0.375, 0.925) 1;
    animation: project-hover 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.315, 0.605, 0.375, 0.925) 1;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(0) rotateX(0) translate3d(0, 0, 130px);
    transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(0) rotateX(0) translate3d(0, 0, 130px);
  }
  h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product-heading">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="">
  <h3>Sample Heading</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a possibility for you to add some JS here ?

Comment: thank you for your interest but i solved it by using 2 separate Div's ...1 for transition and other for animation.